# How to read parquet files with Flink as Case Class (scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, avro, parquet, data-stream

With spark we can easily read parquet files and use it as a Case Class with the following code:

`spark.read.parquet("my_parquet_table").as[MyCaseClass]`

With Flink, I'm having a lot a trouble to do that. My Case Class comes from an Avro schema, so it is a SpecificRecord.

I tried the following:

```
val parquetInputFormat = new ParquetRowInputFormat(new Path(path), messageType)
env.readFile(parquetInputFormat, path)
```

The issue here is the messageType, I was not able to convert my case class nor the avro schema to a valid messageType.
I tried this:

`val messageType = ParquetSchemaConverter.toParquetType(TypeInformation.of(classOf[MyCaseClass], true)`

which ends with the following error:
`class org.apache.flink.formats.avro.typeutils.AvroTypeInfo cannot be cast to class org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.RowTypeInfo`

I could try to use the table-api, but it would mean having to create the all table schema myself  and it would be a pain to maintain.
If someone can indicate me an example of implementation, or propose anything that might help it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After another look on the documentation, I see flink does not support complex types for parquet (array, map, etc), so it is not a valid option for me.

Comment: Hi,
but was this a root cause of the issue you were having?

Comment: Hi @Kristoff, the issue was not directly linked but this limitation was too big to continue this way, and the documentation and the community help is very little on this subject...